# Problem integrating images with new template

Tags: floats, errors

I'm having problems displaying my figures in the new template in which I need to hand in my paper. All the figures are in the same folder as the tex file, and I'm not getting any error messages. Everything runs fine in a different document.

Could someone please point out what's going wrong? Apologies for the long preamble.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=30mm, top=1.5in, bottom=1.0in, columnsep=20pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{abstract} 
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} 

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}} 
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{running title} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text


\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Article Title}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{Name}\thanks{A thank you or further information}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize Bla Uni. \\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\vspace{-5mm}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title
\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers


\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{myPlot1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{myPlot2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{myPlot3}
\caption{my caption}
\label{fig:dataplot}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try omitting the `h` specifier. That doesn't leave much choice if there's no room "here". If you don't want the figure to float, just don't use `figure` at all and use `\captionof...` for the caption. I can't test this because I can't compile your code, obviously. If you need more help, please substitute standard images for yours e.g. `example-image-a.png` etc.  Also, try to make your example more minimal by removing packages and code which is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cfr Thank you but I tried removing the specifier. Not working still. Sorry for including all packages but I wanted to cover all bases.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you substitute `example-image-a` for each of your images?

Comment: Yes, sir. Still no images...

Comment: Please don't call me a sir. I'm not. How are you compiling?

Comment: oops, sorry about that, just reflex. I just hit "quickbuild" if that's what you mean. The images will load if I remove the \begin{figure} code. However, I need all three images to load as a single figure, and with captions, ref, etc. And in the right place not at the end of the document. The way I have it now it's sadly the only way I know how to accomplish the task. Thank you for the help.

Comment: So if you compile that very same code with `example-image-a` substituted for each plot and `\vspace{-5mm}` made into `\vspace{-5mm}}` you don't get the images? To be sure, can you create a new `.tex` file and copy the code from here to there, make those changes and then compile it? Because it works for me. So the problem is not the code if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: The code as posted by @HcN runs fine in an new doc. The images show sided by side though, not aligned vertically as I suppose they should. Mine won't for some reason. Maybe the figures are not stacking in a column as they should in a two column paper? I also tried \begin{figure*} which loads the images but again, at the end of the paper.

Comment: Leave a line between them if you want them stacked. A line break means a space. That is, the output is expected. For your original doc, remove all generated files before recompiling or, failing that, try copy-pasting the contents into another new `.tex` file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you simply forgot a curly bracket to close the `\author` field.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=30mm, top=1.5in, bottom=1.0in, columnsep=20pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{abstract} 
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} 

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}} 
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} 

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{running title} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text


\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
       \textbf{Article Title}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{Name}\thanks{A thank you or further information}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize Bla Uni. \\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title
\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\begin{twocolumn}[
\maketitle % Insert title
                    ]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}\\[1ex]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}\\[1ex]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-c}
    \caption{my caption}
\label{fig:dataplot}
   \end{figure}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I only delete twice loaded package `caption`, move `hyperref` on the end, change figure option from `[h]` to `[htb], and use`twocolumn`and`lipsum` to emulate two column article. As proof, that this work is picture of first page.

[image]

**Note:** If your real picture doesn't appear on the first page, means that they are bigger as presented and will show up on the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that was probably a copy/past error into stack exchange. It's still not running correctly.

Comment: It is running correctly for me. What is the error message you get ?

Comment: No error message at all. That's what's weird. Everything shows up but the images.

Comment: Oh, what are the formats of you images ?

Comment: png -- this runs fine in my other tex doc.

Comment: Indeed, I really cannot see why you would get a problem them. PDF viewer maybe ?

Comment: `\date{}` should not be in `\author{}`. (Well, most of the rest shouldn't be in `\author{}` either, but `\date{}` can be left out and it will work a bit more normally, at least.

Comment: @HcN, I allowed myself edit your answer (I up-vote it). I made small changes, described in your answer and add picture of your code result. If you disagree with this changes, delete them.   At appearing of figures OP should take in mind, that LaTeX require minimal  fraction of text in column/page. If this is not fulfilled, it move figure to the page, where it is or on the end of article.